# Compare Sum Revenue by Month to Trailing 12 Month

Tags: sql, window, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view that takes the revenue of a sku (sku_number) at each source system id (ssid_sales_invoice) and gives me the revenue for the current period which I have but also pulls in the revenue for that same sku from the prior 12 month period aggregated at the same sku and source system id level, to fill in the last column of my screen shot.

I have tried using a window function but do not know if I can specify to only go back 12 months prior and there is not always the same number of ssid_sales_invoice for each sku_number so counting rows doesn't work.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRn8J.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your post to include example data (as part of the post, not as image), the window function you tried and the outcome you expect rsp. information on how your attempts did not work or did not create the desired result.